# Linq-to-Entities: My OrderBy clause isn't ordering

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have a Linq statement which uses a mixture of fluent and dot notation to order, group, order again, then do a `Skip`/`Take` on some entities:

```
(from terms in db.stt_term
 where !terms.deleted && languageIDs.Contains(terms.language_id)
 join concepts in db.stt_concept
    on terms.concept_id equals concepts.id
 where !concepts.deleted && concepts.dictionary_id == dictionaryID
 select terms).GroupBy(t => t.concept_id)
              .Select(grp => new
                                 {
                                     ConceptId = grp.Key,
                                     // the order of the Terms in each grouping should be dictated by the order of the Languages
                                     Terms = grp.OrderBy(t => SqlFunctions.CharIndex(strLangIDs, "_" + t.language_id + "_"))
                                 })
              // now order all the groups by the first term in each
              .OrderBy(grp => grp.Terms.FirstOrDefault().term_translation)
              .Skip(page*conceptsPerPage)
              .Take(conceptsPerPage)
```

Ok, that might be a bit too much to take in without any background explanation, but I'd like to draw your attention to the line

```
Terms = grp.OrderBy(t => SqlFunctions.CharIndex(strLangIDs, "_" + t.language_id + "_"))
```

This is my attempt to attain `IndexOf`-like functionality. I've resorted to this because Linq-to-Entities does not recognise an `IndexOf` call, and the closest thing I can find is `CharIndex` in the functions provided for linq-to-SQL.

`CharIndex` obviously takes a string, whereas what I'm really looking to do here is order `term` entities according to where their `.language_id` property is indexed in an array of integers. So to get around there being no available `IndexOf`, I've transformed the array of integers into a `_`-separated string, then search for a correspondingly-formatted `language_id`.

For example, the array `{15, 1, 3, 4}` becomes `"_15_1_3_4_"`, and I then find the index of, say, `"_3_"` in this string. Terms where `language_id = 15` should then be ordered above terms with `lanaguage_id = 1`.

However, the results show that no ordering takes place.

If I convert that `OrderBy` statement to be

```
Terms = grp.OrderBy(t => t.language_id))
```

Then ordering *does* take place. But no ordering takes place when I use my, admittedly, slightly hack-ey call to `SqlFunctions.CharIndex`.

Can anyone explain why `CharIndex` isn't ordering as I expect it to?

Comment: The possibility that you are using EntityFramework and Linq-to-SQL is nearly 0%... Which one of the two?

Comment: Try looking with the SQL Profiler at the query generated. I'll say that the problem is that you can't have two sorts (one outside and one inside). I think the SQL Server will respect only the most external one

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand why there's a problem citing both the EntityFramework and Linq-to-SQL - I'm querying using the EntityFramework, and referencing a method in the SQL Functions namespace which was built for Linq-to-SQL.

Comment: If you are using [System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.CharIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487160(v=vs.100).aspx) then its description is `This function can only appear within a **LINQ to Entities** query.`

Comment: And yet I can see its presence in the emitted SQL: `CAST(CHARINDEX('_1_3_4_15_', N'_' +  CAST( [Extent3].[language_id] AS nvarchar(max)) + N'_') AS int) AS [C1]`

Comment: Entity Framework == linq-to-entities, but EF != linq-to-sql, and linq-to-entities != linq-to-sql. Still, found the problem. Look at the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inverting the searched with the target... [SqlFunctions.CharIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487160(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public static Nullable<int> CharIndex(
    string toSearch,
    string target
)
```

invert the two.

From

```
SqlFunctions.CharIndex(strLangIDs, "_" + t.language_id + "_")
```

to

```
SqlFunctions.CharIndex("_" + t.language_id + "_", strLangIDs)
```

Comment: Perfect! That works. but may I be so bold as to point out that Microsoft may have written the descriptions for those two parameters the wrong way around. For example, "_toSearch: The string expression to be searched._" and "_target: The string expression to be found._" You can understand why I got those the wrong way around, right?

Comment: @awj The sentences were surely badly written. In fact I checked the CHARINDEX page :) `CHARINDEX ( expressionToFind ,expressionToSearch [ , start_location ] )`

Comment: Ok, just for future reference, in case anyone else is puzzled by these params, the CHARINDEX reference (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) lists and describes the params correctly, whereas the SqlFunctions.CharIndex reference (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487162%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) appears to have its descriptions assigned to the wrong params.